# Multiple random results in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create 64 squares and give each a unique background color. I'm pretty close, but I can only seem to get one random color.

```
function randomCol() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); 
}

$(function(){
  for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
        $('<div class="square"></div>').insertAfter(".starter");
        $(".square").css({'background':'#' + randomCol()});
  }
 });
```

Comment: "one random color", as in, the call to `Math.random()` is returning the same number every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(".square")` selects **all existing** elements with class `square`, so you are assigning the same color to each element.

You only want to assign the color to the just created one:

```
$('<div class="square"></div>')
   .css('background', '#' + randomCol())
   .insertAfter(".starter");
```

---

Two suggestions:

- Create the DOM node only once and clone it (might not actually be an improvement, you have to try).
- Insert the elements all at once to avoid multiple page reflows.

```
$(function(){
    var $node = $('<div class="square"></div>'),
        $elements = $();
    for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
        $elements = $elements.add($node.clone().css('background','#' + randomCol()));
    }
    $('.starter').after($elements);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the performance tip! You're doing God's work, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the background style to the square class. Because all your div's use the same class, all your div's will use the last color you generated.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
        $('<div id="square' + i + '"></div>').insertAfter(".starter");
        $("#square" + i).css({'background':'#' + randomCol()});
  }
 });
```

Comment: with this, you'll create 64 square ids

Comment: I realize this. Felix Kling's answer is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You apply the same color to every Div, you can use the `each` method from JQuery

```
$(function(){
  for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
    $('<div class="square"></div>').insertAfter(".starter");
  }
  $(".square").each(
     function(s){
       $(s).css({'background':'#' + randomCol()})
     }
  );
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
    $('<div class="square"></div>').
       insertAfter(".starter").
       css({'background':'#' + randomCol()});
  }
});
```